# Find Control in code behind - multiple results controls - nth occurence

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following problem.

I have a `asp:textbox` on the page, runat server with an id of say `txt`
This text box is in a `<div>`, nothing special. ie:

```
<div>
 <asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

The problem is there is some java script which when you push the corresponding button it doubles (copies) the div. This is by design. It is meant to.

When you hit save but at the bottom of the page on a asp:Button, it can't find the value I need because it returns two results.

In the code behind:

```
(Textbox) blah = (Textbox)senderbutton.FindControl("txt");

string test = blah.text
```

But the result is essentially-->        "The value in the textbox , The value in the textbox"

I.e. it is there twice. I have worked around this by doing the following:

```
string[] test = blah.text.split(new[] { ',' })
```

and then only calling the second value in the array or whatever.

**BUT**, now I have this situation but the problem is that a user can enter a string with a ' , ' in it, hence the splitting goes to crap....

So can I find a control with an id, but only find the nth occurence of it in the code behind?

Comment: So why exactly do you copy the DIV in javascript? Maybe there is another, better solution for that.

Comment: lol yeah I thought about that. That is my backup option. Problem is I would need to change it in like a couple hundred places so...trying to an easy way out...

Comment: It's by design and it's not always right - do you need the second textbox in codebehind? if not, remove the Id when copying/cloning it

Comment: But can you explain why it is as it is? Why implement a hack (which might work in most cases) if the root problem can be solved?

Comment: because it was like that when I got here... :S  ... Trust me, I know it is a bad solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to give different name(like **txt0,txt1**...) for each copy of the input controls. 
You can do this using javascript up on client click(prior to form submission) of your asp button

-- **Javascript method**

```
    function ModifyName() {
        var x = 0;
        $("input[name='txt']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + x);
            x++;
        });
    }
```

-- **asp:Button**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
   OnClientClick="ModifyName();" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

So in code behind you can get the values like this...

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var resultArr = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(x => x.Contains("txt"))
            .Select(x => Request.Form[x]).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, thats actually a good idea :)   Thanks mate I got it doing what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very nice solution, but you could examine the Request.Form collection directly upon postback and write some code to process your dynamically added textbox fields.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be: avoiding copying the div in js. Since you said "This is by design. It is meant to."(even I really doubt it), there are some alternative solutions:

(1) Don't use the default submit behavior of the form. That is, in the click (js) event of the save button, organize the data in the form and then submit it.

(2) Modify the second(copied) textbox's id so that its id is different from the original one, and then get the data in code behind.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you using `FindControl` method to find the control when you can directly access the `txt` control from code behind.

You can get results easily

```
String test = txt.Text;
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as the control is being duplicated client side.